# How to nudge geom_segment with categorical coordinates

Tags: r, ggplot2

In my plot, `x` axis is numeric while `y` is categorical, and I have different types of objects drawn - points, segments, text labels etc. Sample dataset:

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- fread('
subject type start stop
  sbjA    U    10    20
  sbjA    D    15    25
  sbjB    U     0    10
  sbjB   pnt   25
  sbjC    D    30    40
  sbjC    U    30    50
', fill=T)

ggplot(dt1, aes(x=start, y=subject)) + 
  geom_segment(data = dt1[type=='U',], aes(xend=stop,yend=subject), col='red', size=3, alpha=0.5)+
  geom_segment(data = dt1[type=='D',], aes(xend=stop,yend=subject), col='blue', size=3, alpha=0.5)+
  geom_point(data = dt1[type=='pnt',])
```

For line segments, I want to show them not overlapping but adjacent, i.e. instead of this
[image: what I have]
I want to have this:
[image: what I want]
How can I achieve it, with categorical `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `position_dodge`, but with `geom_linerange`:

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=start, y=subject)) + 
    geom_linerange(data = dt1[type %in% c('U', 'D')],
        aes(xmin=start,xmax=stop, color = type),
        size=3, alpha=0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
    scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue')) +
    geom_point(data = dt1[type=='pnt',])
```

[image]

`geom_segment` + `position_dodge` looks weird :(

```
ggplot(dt1, aes(x=start, y=subject)) + 
    geom_segment(data = dt1[type %in% c('U', 'D')],
        aes(xend=stop,yend=subject, color = type),
        size=3, alpha=0.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.2))+
    scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'blue')) +
    geom_point(data = dt1[type=='pnt',])
```

[image]

Comment: oh I didn't know about that type of object! Thanks!

Comment: @VasilyA check also what mt1022 silently did with your two calls to geom_segment - it's now only a *single call*to geom_linerange and color is in aes. nice answer. Interesting with geom_segment, only y is dodged, not yend. Guess one would need to modify the position object

Comment: thanks @tjebo. In my real scenario I have to use separate calls because I have many other types of objects, so defining them in `aes()` would be too much of a mess :/